# Room - only allow 1 item to have boolean set to true

Tags: android, observable, android-room, android-livedata

Using room with live data... one thing I can't figure out is this:

```
object1.isSelected == true;
object2.isSelected == false;
object3.isSelected == false;
```

if I set 'isSelected' to true on object3, I want it to become false in object 1.

**Is there a way to do this without observing both objects, making the switch, and then updating both objects?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a class.

```
public class OneBoolean{
    private Object[] objects;

    public OneBoolean(Object objects..){
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    private void setSelected(int index){
        // This is first approach. You can store the previous selected index and just change it false, and change this true
        for(int i=0 ; i<objects.length() ; i++){
            objects[i].isSelected = (i==index);
        }
    }
}
```